# NumPy all Function Across Third Dimension of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, logical-operators

Consider the ndarray with the following dimensions `(1200,2600,200)`

I am looking to assess whether all the values along the third dimension, or axis=2, at point [i,j] in this array are all the same value. For example, I'd use the following to assess the presence of all zeroes. I'm using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
array  = np.random.randint(0.00, 75.00, size=(1200, 2600, 200))
logical = array.all(axis=2) == 0
```

This executes, however returns the boolean True at all array points, even where zeroes do not populate the entire third dimension. What alterations are required to yield the desired result?

Comment: Compare to your desired value first, then apply `all`. For instance: `(array == 0).all(axis=2)`, or equivalently: `np.all(array == 0, axis=2)`.

Comment: `all` does a logical AND.  It is true if ANY element is 0.  You might try using `any` and take the inverse of that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [numpy.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) states that it

> Test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True.

---

So you need to do one of

```
(array == 0).all(axis=2)

np.all(array == 0, axis=2)
```